# add_custom_command fails to generate target file

Tags: cmake, flatbuffers

I am trying to generate headers from flatbuffer schema. So I have this function:

```
function(compile_flatbuffers_schema_to_cpp SRC_FBS)
  find_program(FLATBUFFERS_FLATC_EXECUTABLE NAMES flatc)
  get_filename_component(SRC_FBS_DIR ${SRC_FBS} PATH)
  string(REGEX REPLACE "\\.fbs$" "_generated.h" GEN_HEADER ${SRC_FBS})
  message(STATUS "filepath ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${SRC_FBS}")
  message(STATUS "output dir is ${SRC_FBS_DIR}")
  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${GEN_HEADER}
    COMMAND "${FLATBUFFERS_FLATC_EXECUTABLE}" -c --no-includes --gen-mutable
            --gen-object-api --gen-compare
            --reflect-names
            "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${SRC_FBS}"
    DEPENDS flatc
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
endfunction()
```

and I call this from my cmake `compile_flatbuffers_schema_to_cpp(dir_name/temp.fbs)`

But i do not see `temp_generate.h` anywhere. File `temp.fbs` exists at that path and cmake file is in same directory as that of `dir_name`.

Comment: Are you sure `flatc` is even running? make a spelling error in one of the command line options to it, if that does not error out, there is a problem with your CMake definition.

Comment: @Aardappel that's the problem I have tried proving non-existent file, it does not error out. But how do I debug cmake definition? I do not see anything wrong with the arguments.

Comment: By itself, `add_custom_command` isn't run. It should be `add_custom_command` which depends on the custom command OUTPUT, or `add_executable`/`add_library` which lists files from the command's OUTPUT. Show corresponded code in your post.

Comment: Thanks, now I added `add_custom_target(fbs_header DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${GEN_HEADER})` in my function. And for my target I do `add_dependencies(target_name fbs_header)`. It prints message generating <path>/*.h but I do not see that file generated.

Comment: You can add a comment to `add_custom_command()` that will output when it runs.  But it doesn't look like `add_custom_target()` and `add_custom_command()` refer to the same file, they use different directories.